# How to add store address to invoice email

Tags: magento-1.7, transactional-mail

We would like to show the store's address at the top of the invoice email which is sent to customers when they place an order. Specifically, I would like to insert the value from the *Invoice and Packing Slip Design* section in the admin panel because this section can include the VAT number.

How can I insert the *sales/identity/address* value into a transactional email template? I have tried using the following variable but it comes out blank:

```
{{sales/identity/address}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Magento init variables for invoice email here:

> Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template_Abstract::_addEmailVariables

You may rewrite this method with this class `Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template`